# Android Studio SDK

Tags: android

I'm a student system admin for small college CS program, and I'm installing Android Studio on our lab machines for the students to use. I have studio installed in /opt so that all users who log in have the ability to launch it however I'm stumped at where to put the SDK's. Android Studio is pretty picky about the permissions of the SDK location, requiring read/write/execute from what I can see.

I want to ensure that the SDK's are globally located for all users who log into that specific machine but I'm not sure of where the appropriate location should be. I currently have them sitting in /usr/sdk with it being 777 but from what I've read /usr should not be holding writable directories.